# Refit 6 not working when android project built with unity

Tags: c#, android, rest, unity-game-engine, refit

I'm using [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) 6 in unity for rest calls but when project is built for Android getting below error.

```
Message: MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'Refit.Implementation.Generated+*InterfaceName*' not found.
Stack Trace:
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
Refit.RestService.For[T] (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, Refit.IRequestBuilder`1[T] builder) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.Action`1[T].Invoke (T obj) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.Action`1[T].Invoke (T obj) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction.Invoke () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1].Invoke (T1 handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchPress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, System.Boolean pressed, System.Boolean released) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchEvents () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
```

I tried adding link.xml but didn't help.

Any help on this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they added support for code generation in 2021.2 (https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/roslyn-analyzers.html)

But how you use that with refit, I don't know. I'd like to get refit working with Unity as well.

Comment: OP specifically asked for help with using Refit in Unity. Providing an answer that does not address the question doesn't seem to move the conversation in the right direction. Either provide additional information about how this helps answer the question, or remove your response.

Comment: Well, I would have just commented but stackoverflow won't let me because my rep is too low.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31564254)

Comment: Kent I'm well aware of how little my answer is contributing but, like I said, since I can't simply comment it will have to do. The Asker has not asked for clarification, so I don't know why you bothered to mention that. Refit uses Roslyn code generation which wasn't added to Unity until recently but it's not well documented how to take advantage of it.